# Placing Matplotlib plot title to the right margin

Tags: python, matplotlib

It there a way to move the image title to the right margin. Obviously, this does not work:

```
axarr[x,y].set_title(np.argmax(pred[i]), loc='right')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title` passes keyword arguments down to `matplotlib.text.Text`. This allows the use of `rotation` and `position` arguments to rotate and move the axes title. To set it on the right margin you can do

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_title("Title", rotation=-90, position=(1, 0.5), ha='left', va='center')
```

[image]

You can adjust the spacing and position of the title by changing the `position` argument which is `(x, y)` in figure coordinates.

Comment: This approach appears to no longer work in matplotlib 3.8.2. `ax.text(1, 0.5, 'Title', rotation=-90, ha='left', va='center')` produces the required result though.