# How can I set the subplot-title to middle of the right?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The example [from an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625260/placing-matplotlib-plot-title-to-the-right-margin) sets the subplot-title to the middle of the plot height. If I run it, [it's in the middle of the title height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw20J.png). Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Thanks if anyone can help.

Changing position-parameters did not change the position low enough to reach the middle.

Comment: `ax.text(1, 0.5, 'Title', rotation=-90, ha='left', va='center')`?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)